Tkinter Iterating through two dictionaries and creating a grid
I have a Python application that builds itself using a JSON file, for customization purposes. But, I realized that I have no way of dealing with overflow, and now that it has a lot of stuff it either overflows to the sides or to the bottom.
This is the code that works for small amounts of widgets, but can't adapt.
def BuildApplication():
    for key in jsonValueDict:
        key = ttk.Label(topContainer, text="Insira a coluna " + jsonValueDict[key])
        key.pack()
        for key in jsonInputDict:
            key = ttk.Entry(topContainer)
            key.pack()
            break
    btnSubmit = ttk.Button(midContainer, text="Finalizar", command=Submit)
    btnSubmit.pack()
    btnExport = ttk.Button(midContainer, text="Exportar", command=Export)
    btnExport.pack()
    print("Finished loading.")

I saw some people talking about using "for x in range" loops but I can't since it's based on a dictionary and it can have multiple sizes. I tried using modulus to change it every x amount of widgets, but since I have a label and an input it doesn't work.
I tried using 'counter' variables that increased during iteration, but it either just created a downward stair or just completely messed up the buttons.
I need this to become a grid, "after x amount of widgets, move to the side and start counting again"

It's very confusing the way you keep reusing the variable key. You should avoid reusing variables like this.

You can use a separate counter variable that you increment during the loop. When it reaches the column limit, you can start a new row in the grid and set the counter back to 0.

This worked, also fixed the variable names, I was worried about that but felt too lazy to change it.

What is the point of inner for loop since break is called?

I needed the order to be label-button-label-button but if I just ran two for loops it ran all the values in jsonValueDict and then ran all the values in jsonInputDict, so it was actually label-label... and then button-button..., running a nested for loop without break actually runs all of the values in jsonInputDict iirc, I'm not sure why but it only worked when I added the break

What I mean is that if break is called, the inner for loop is not necessary at all.

I can't reply to comments as my rep is not high enough, but for the problem of getting the widgets to go label button label button in sequence. You can just make two lists of labels and buttons and then start packing or gridding them.
For example:
label_dict = json.loads(<filepath>)
label_list = label_dict.values() 

# do the same thing for buttons if you get it from a json 
button_list = ... 

# assuming the two lists are of the same length 
for i in range(len(label_list)): 
    l = Label(<parent>, text = label_list[i]) 
    l.pack() 
    # if you don't have a list for button you can just make them here
    b = Button(<parent>, text = button_list[i]) 
    b.pack() 

Do not that if you do use a for loop to make a bunch of widget and wish to bind them somehow, you need to specify the widget in the bind method in the loop.
i.e.
for ...: # some for loop, didn't specify anything 
    w = <Some Widget>
    w.bind("<Some Event>", lambda e, w=w: <some function/code that modifies or uses w>)


Not sure if I understood this correctly but if you have 10 items and try to put it in a grid of 2 rows then you want it to create 5 columns of 2 rows(?). I can't tell what you are trying to achieve exactly as I don't know the specification of the two json dictionaries. But assuming that if L = the number of column labels and R = the number of rows then L*R <= number of keys in the input dictionary then I would do something like:
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * # overrides default widgets 
import json

def BuildApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label_path, entry_path, rows): 
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rows = rows 
    
        label_dict = json.loads(label_path)
        entry_dict = json.loads(entry_path) 

        self.grid_rowconfigure(list(range(rows)), weight=1, uniform="rows")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(list(range(len(label_dict))), weight=1, uniform="cols")
        col_ind = 0 
        for lk in label_dict.keys(): 
            l = Label(self, text=label_dict[lk], font=<whatever font>)
            l.grid(column=col_ind, row=0, sticky="nsew") 
            
            row_ind = 0
            for ek in entry_dict.leys(): 
                e = Entry(self) 
                e.insert(0, entry_dict[ek]) 
                e.grid(column=col_ind, row=row_ind, sticky="nsew")
                row_ind += 1 
            col_ind += 1 

I think that covers what you want(?). I don't know where you wanted the buttons so I didn't add that to the code. I personally recommend grid over pack if you are dealing with a lot of widgets as it is easier to manage placement.
I did not run this code btw, just typed it straight into stackoverflow.
